# How to upload 100 MB file in to sharepoint using java?

Tags: java, sharepoint

We've a requirement to upload file size of 100MB in to sharepoint.With the code below,we get an exception java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

```
if(toaddInsideFolder)
            url = restServiceURL.toString() + "/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folder + "')"+url;
        else
            url = restServiceURL.toString() + "/Folders/GetByUrl('" + folder + "')"+url;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        //To receive xml response add below header to http get request
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        httppost.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", getRequestDigest());

byte[] binary = new byte[(int) len];
            File file = new File(URL);
            FileInputStream localFileInputStream = null;
                localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                localFileInputStream.read(binary);
        HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(binary);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);


 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.executePost(httppost);
        String statusLine = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        String jsonresponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: `localFileInputStream.read(binary);` is unlikely to read the file’s entire contents.  Use a FileEntity instead.

Comment: Thanks @VGR.Using FileEntity,It's taking 20 mins to upload 60MB file.Do we've any faster approach?